# turtle in Java not working - class

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I'm having difficulty with my class structure. I've posted my code below. The problem I'm having is determining how to use scanner values in smaller functions. I'm trying to use my N and S values for my two snowflake functions.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Snowflake {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter S: ");
    int S = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter N: ");
    int N = sc.nextInt();

    Turtle turtle  = new Turtle(0, 0, 60);

    public void snowflakepart(S, N) {
      int z = 1;

      if (N > 0) {
        turtle.goForward(S);

        if (N > 1) {
          turtle.turnLeft(120.0);

          while (z <= 5) {
            snowflakepart(S/3, N-1);
            turtle.turnRight(60.0);
            turtle.turnRight(180.0);
            turtle.turnLeft(180.0);
            turtle.goForward(S);
            turtle.turnRight(180.0);    
          }
        }
      }
    }

    public void drawSnowflake(S,N) {    
      int y = 1;

      while (y <= 6) {
        snowflakepart(S,N);
        turtle.turnLeft(60.0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you running into an error of some sort?

Comment: Yes, i'm getting X's in my eclipse program saying that I need to change S and N. Also, i'm not sure where to initialize the turtle function since it is needed for both drawsnowflake and snowflakepart.

Comment: This code does not compile. Even if it did, you do nothing with your turtle after constructing it.

Comment: You'll have to give a better explanation of your problem than "determining how to use scanner values in smaller functions".

Comment: @2rs2ts So the basic idea is that i'm trying to initialize the turtle and use the following two functions to draw out a snowflake. I'm adjusting it atm but do you have any feedback on what I could change?

Comment: Fixed your indents, but you seem to have a syntax error with closing the main method only after the two other methods. Perhaps that was just a typo on your part?

Comment: @t0mppa I think I got somewhere. Now my only problem is that I don't know how to make N and S global variables that I can use in both void functions.

Comment: It doesn't look like they need to be global. You could call `drawSnowFlake()` from your main method and give it the `N` and `S` values that user just provided. Also, you need to define what type of variables `N` & `S` are in both of the method declarations. From the looks of it, perhaps `int`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess since you're not providing much information. The biggest problem I see with your code is that you're putting the wrong thing in the wrong place. Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
public class Snowflake {
        Turtle turtle;
     //Create a Turtle object here since you'll use it in this class' methods.
        public Snowflake(){
            turtle  = new Turtle(0, 0, 60);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          //Get a reference to your SnowFlake object here and then use this part for
          //user interaction only
            SnowFlake flake = new Snowflake();
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter S: ");
            int S = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter N: ");
            int N = sc.nextInt();

        //Call your functions here with the parameter your users just entered

        }

          //These 2 methods belong to the SnowFlake class and so they need to be 
          //declared in its body
            public void snowflakepart(int S, int N) {
                int z = 1;
                if(N > 0) {
                    turtle.goForward(S);
                    if(N>1){
                        turtle.turnLeft(120.0);
                        while(z<=5){
                            snowflakepart(S/3, N-1);
                            turtle.turnRight(60.0);
                        turtle.turnRight(180.0);
                    turtle.turnLeft(180.0);
                    turtle.goForward(S);
                    turtle.turnRight(180.0);    
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            public void drawSnowflake(int S, int N) {    
                int y = 1;
                while(y <= 6){
                    snowflakepart(S,N);
                    turtle.turnLeft(60.0);

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @2rs2ts but i'm still having the same problem with S and N. After I close off the main function, it tells me that S and N aren't being used.

Comment: @user2908101 if you copied spacitron's code directly as it is above, of course not. You need to give the turtle some instructions. I suggest invoking your `Snowflake` class' methods and seeing what happens.

Comment: @user2908101 I"d like to help you further but if you don't know how to call methods maybe you need to follow a few beginners tutorials before expecting others to solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you guys. I've figured it out.